# Integral domain $R$ with fraction field $K$ such that for every $u \in K$, the subring $R[u]$ of $K$ is flat $R$-module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, prufer-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain with fraction field $K$. If for every $u \in K$, the subring  $R[u]$ of $K$ is a flat $R$-module, then is it true that $R$ is a Prufer domain ?

If $R$ were moreover a GCD domain, then I could prove that $R$ is a Prufer domain; but without the GCD assumption, I don't see what would happen. If every overring of $R$ i.e. subring $S$ of $K$ with $R \subseteq S \subseteq K$, then also $R$ would be Prufer (this is standard). But I am considering only very special type of overrings.